# Proof if $n_k < n_{k+1}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $n_k \geq k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: inequality

So if we proceed by induction on $k$, the base case $k = 1$ works since $n_1 \geq 1$ is true because $1$ is the smallest integer in $\mathbb{N}$.

For the induction hypothesis, we have that $n_k \geq k$, and we want to show that $n_{k+1} \geq k+1$. We are given in the problem that $n_{k+1} > n_k$, and combining that with the induction hypothesis, we have: $n_{k+1} > n_k \geq k$. So we know that $n_{k+1} > k$, but if we add $1$ to both sides we get $n_{k+1} + 1 > k+1$ which isn't quite what we wanted. If we add $1$ only to the right side, we have either $n_{k+1} \geq k+1$ or $n_{k+1} < k+1$ (or $n_{k+1} \leq k+1$). Obviously we want the first inequality to be true, so how do we prove that the latter inequalities are not possible cases?

Comment: $n_k1+\frac{k}{2}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Do you have a definition of $n_k$? Or some sort of restriction? You seem to assume that $n_k\in\Bbb{N}$. That should be stated.

Comment: @KSmarts Yes it is, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you work with Intergers. For integer the following is true:

$n>k \Leftrightarrow n\geq k+1$

This is because $k+1$ is the smallest integer number which is greater than $k$.